# If $a$, $b$, $c$ are rational and $a+b+c=0$, show that the roots of $(b+c-a)x^2 + (c+a-b)x + (a+b-c)=0$ are rational.

Tags: polynomials, roots, quadratics

If $a$, $b$, $c$ are rational and $a+b+c=0$, show that the roots of $(b+c-a)x^2 + (c+a-b)x + (a+b-c)=0$ are rational.

My Attempt:

Given,
$$(b+c-a)x^2 + (c+a-b)x + (a+b-c)=0$$
Comparing above equation with $Ax^2+Bx+C=0$, we get:
\begin{align}
A&=b+c-a=-2a \\
B&=c+a-b=-2b \\
C&=a+b-c=-2c
\end{align}
Now,
\begin{align}
B^2-4AC 
&= (-2b)^2-4(-2a)(-2c) \\
&= 4b^2-16ac.
\end{align}

Comment: Hint:  As you remark, the polynomial is the same as $-2(ax^2+bx+c)$.  Can you spot a root?

Comment: @lulu yes, that's what the $A,B,C$ are. Note that you can divide through by $-2$ to get $ax^2 + bx +c = 0$. Observe that $1$ is a root of the equation - how can you find the other?

Comment: I had not noticed that $1$ was a root ... but it is easy to show the discriminant is a perfect square.

Comment: @platty  are you the OP?  The name change confused me.  If $a\neq 0$ then the two roots sum to $\frac b{a}$

Comment: Not OP, just giving a hint :)

Answer (score 3):

Observe that $x_1=1$ is a root.
If $a=0$, it is the only root. Else,
the product of the roots is

$$1.x_2=\frac {a+b-c}{b+c-a} $$
$$=\frac {c}{a}\in \Bbb Q $$

Comment: Then there's only one root, because the first coefficient of the quadratic is $0$. And since $x_1=1$ is still a root, it's the only root, and all of them.

Comment: It's not defined of course, but the point is that it's irrelevant. x1=1 and then the proof is done, in that case.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}4b^2-16ac &=4(b^2-4ac)
\\&=4(b^2+4a(a+b))\\
&=4(b^2 +4ab+4a^2)\\
&=(2(b+2a))^2 \end{align}

Hence the roots are $$\frac{-B\pm2(b+2a)}{2A}$$

which is rational.

Note that if $A=0$, the equation is linear.

Remark: something to think about, what happens if $a=b=c=0$, are all the roots still rational?

Answer (score 1):

Multiplying by $-1/2$, the equation can be rewritten as
$$
ax^2+bx+c=ax^2+bx-(a+b)=(x-1)(ax+a+b).
$$